# Definition of spectrum of $\mathcal{L}$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, differential-operators

What does it mean for the spectrum of eigenvalues of differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ to be anywhere continuous? The textbook that I'm using doesn't give the definition of a spectrum either. This is a textbook in Multivariable Calculus, not functional analysis (which I haven't learned). All the definitions I've seen have to do strongly with functional analysis.

Comment: If it is in a Multivariable Calculus book it probably means the set of all $\lambda$ for which $\mathcal L f =\lambda f$ has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they mean the following. Continuous spectrum of $\mathcal L$ is the subset of all those $\lambda\in\mathbb K$ for which $\mathcal L - \lambda I$ is injective, is not surjective and has dense image, where $I$ is the identity operator.